# Android: How to set drawable for Expandable List View

Tags: android, drawable, expandablelistview

In my application i set `android:groupIndicator` for Expandable List View but images are not show correctly and have elongation, these are my codes:

```
<ExpandableListView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
            android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator"/>
```

group_indicator.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tick" android:state_empty="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/minus1" android:state_expanded="true"></item>
</selector>
```

below is snapshot of what i say:

[image]

How can i fix it???

Answer (score 1):

You have to create image set for diiferent screen size  Eg:

MDPI (Baseline): 16 px (drawable)
HDPI    : 24 px (drawable-hdpi)
XHDPI   : 32 px (drawable-xhdpi)
XXHDPI  : 48 px
XXXHDPI : 64 px

It is important to create the icon with a specific ratio. plz have a look at 
[this](http://www.creativefreedom.co.uk/icon-designers-blog/android-4-1-icon-size-guide-made-simple/)

The Small / Contextual Icons are responsible for list icon

**Other solutions: 'Set image padding as null OR you can create a 9 patch image'**

Answer (score 0):

I think you have maintain in different  drawable folders then it will be appear correctly....

Yes you need to put your images in 4 folders like hdpi,ldpi,mdpi,xhdpi Once see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more info

Comment: i don't understand what you said. i toke image in all drawable-ldpi , hdpi and others.

Comment: how can i get these versions?

Answer (score 0):

The image you use for group indicator has to be as high as the height of the line, even if you have to add extra transparent space, for example, this image is 20x60, the 60px of height are mostly transparent:

[image: arrow down list]